# Making sure Git knows that deleting local branch is safe after PR is merged

Tags: git, git-merge

I made a pull request to merge `my-feature-branch` into `master` on GitHub. The repo owner added one more commit to my branch, merged to `master`, and delete `my-feature-branch` using GitHub GUI. I updated with `git pull master`, deleted the tracking branch with `git pull --prune`. But when I tried to remove the local feature branch with `git branch --delete my-feature-branch`, I got `error: The branch 'my-feature-branch' is not fully merged.`

I kinda understand why Git said it; `my-feature-branch` was never merged into `master` in my local repo (it was only done in the remote repo). And I can of course disregard this message with `git branch -D my-feature-branch`.

But in this case, it's clear that nothing will be lost by deleting `my-feature-branch` in the local repo, since it's reachable from the `master` commit created by merging my PR.

Usually Git is very good at figuring out whether something is safe to do or not. Could I have done things better and avoided the `not fully merged` message?

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether the branch was merged remotely or locally; it's all the same to Git. Please post the output of e.g. `git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate`.

Comment: Also, what branch were you on when you did the first `git pull`? Do you have a remote named `master`?

Comment: is the local  my-feature-branch in sync with the upstream "my-feature-branch" which has been modified by the guy.

Comment: @ScottWeldon It's hard to post output of git log --all because there's too much irrelevant stuff by now. But I was on the master branch when I did it, and yes I have a remote called `master`. I think there is no way to pull `my-feature-branch` from remote any more because it doesn't exist there?

Comment: @z_ it's not in sync because the guy committed, merged to master, and then deleted the upstream `my-feature-branch` since the last time we were in sync.

Comment: To clarify: right now if I `git checkout my-feature-branch`, the message is `Your branch is based on 'origin/my-feature-branch', but the upstream is gone. (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)`

Comment: Correct. The commits should still be there (since they were merged into `master`), but the remote branch isn't there, so you can't pull. Would you be able to post truncated output from the `git log` command? I'm mainly interested in the few commits after the tip of `my-feature-branch`.

Comment: Alternatively, is this a public repo? I can dig through the history myself if so.

Comment: Another idea: did the repo owner only *add* commits, or did they amend or rebase any of your commits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125549/discussion-between-scott-weldon-and-max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, it shouldn't matter whether the branch was merged remotely or locally; it's all the same to Git. This is what a normal history for the situation you describe might look like:

```
*--*--*--*--*--*--*---C [master]
    \                /
     *--*--*--*--A--B
                 |
         [my-feature-branch]
```

where `A` is the last commit that you made, on your local version of `my-feature-branch`. `B` is the commit that the repo owner made, and `C` is the merge commit.

When you are on `master` and do `git branch --delete my-feature-branch`, all Git does is check if commit `A` is an ancestor of commit `C`. You can simulate this check with:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor my-feature-branch master
```

(This command will return 0 for success, 1 for failure.)

---

I don't (yet) know why this check is failing for you, but I have a workaround that should reveal why. Do:

```
git checkout my-feature-branch
git branch my-feature-bak # add backup of original feature branch, if desired
git rebase master
```

Since your branch has already been merged into `master`, most / all of the commits should be skipped during the rebase. Anything that remains will be something that hasn't been merged into `master`, for whatever reason.

Next, inspect the output of:

```
git log my-feature-branch..master
```

to see what happened.

If there are any remaining commits that you want to be included in the repo, then you can create new branches and/or cherry-pick the commits as needed.

Answer (score -1):

Check out to your feature branch, and try `git pull` again.

(`git checkout my-feature-branch`, then `git pull`)

Then, checkout to master again and see if the branch is merged:

`git checkout master`, `git branch --merged`

You should be able to delete your branch with `git branch -d my-feature-branch` once both branches are updated; it seems you may have only updated master from the remote.

Comment: When I do `git pull`, I get the error message `Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'my-feature-branch' from the remote, but no such ref was fetched`. I think this is because this branch was deleted in the remote repo before I got a chance to pull.

Comment: Even if the remote branch still existed, this shouldn't make a difference. Git is able to tell that a branch has been merged even if your local version is behind the remote version.

Comment: @ScottWeldon Yes, unless there were changes on the local version of the branch that were not included for some reason when the merge occurred.